# How does this JavaScript-pattern works: Namespaced constructor

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm having problems to understand how this operation:

```
tmp.setAttribute(i, prop[i]);
```

goes through in this for-loop. How prop-array creates 2 arguments. As I understand `var = i` is just a variable right? But apparently it becomes the 1:st argument in the method just like that?

Thanks for your time.

http://jsbin.com/ozoqob/2/edit

```
var MYAPP = MYAPP || {}; 

MYAPP.dom = {};
   MYAPP.dom.Element = function(type, prop){
     var tmp = document.createElement(type);
     for (var i in prop) {
       tmp.setAttribute(i, prop[i]);
       /*
       WHAT I DONT UNDERSTAND IS HOW THIS FOR-LOOP DIVIDE THE ARRAY IN TWO ARGUMENTS?? BEACAUSE 'I' IS JUST A VARIABLE WHICH IS USED TO LOOP THRU THE ARRAY BUT APPARENTLY NOT RIGHT?
       */
       console.log(i); // how? is this arguments divided?
       console.log(prop[i]);
     }
  return tmp; 
   };

var el1 = new MYAPP.dom.Element(
       'a',
       {href:'http://phpied.com'}
   );

console.log(el1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass an object as the 2nd argument to the method. You then enumerate the properties of that object with a `for...in` loop. At every iteration of the loop, `i` will refer to the identifier of a property of the object, and `prop[i]` will therefore refer to the value of that property:

```
var prop = {
    prop1: "value1",
    prop2: "value2"
};

for (var i in prop) {
    console.log(i); // "prop1", "prop2"
    console.log(prop[i]); // "value1", "value2"
}
```

This behaviour is explained [in the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x12.6.4), and is summed up by this line if you imagine `P` is `i` in the above example:

> Let *P* be the name of the next property of *obj* whose [[Enumerable]] attribute is true.

Comment: Exactly try this for example for document, you will see it better:
`for (var i in document) { console.log(i+": "+document[i]); }`
Each object in JS is let's say traversable so this is equivalent: window.document and window["document"]

Comment: @JamesAllardice I c what u're saying is like this : var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z']; var result = '\n'; for (var i in a) { result += 'index: ' + i + ', value: ' + a[i] + '\n'; } ￼The result is: " index: 0, value: a index: 1, value: b index: 2, value: c index: 3, value: x. Now in my case this obj (array) has just 1 element right :) ?

Answer (score 1):

2 concepts:

1. every object in JavaScript is a hash table thus you can access its property value by a key e.g. `obj[key]`;
2. the for-in loop in JavaScript loops keys in the target object (instead of looping values)

In your code, `for (var i in prop)` loops all the keys in object `prop` and stores each key in `i`. So, for each key `i`, you can get its value by `prop[i]`.

Comment: Sorry, I have no knowledge of PHP. just let you know that the for in loop is different from other language such as C# which is looping values instead.